# Why does Windows 10 1909 notify me of download completion four times?

Tags: windows-10-v1909

When I'm downloading files with Edge (I haven't tried with other browsers, for Reasons), if I'm looking at an Edge window, I don't get a notification in the taskbar notification area. However, if *any* other window, no matter the size or position, has the focus, I will get *four* identical notifications. Why isn't one enough?

Comment: The notification comes within Edge (that is within the Edge window boundaries. That is where it asks you if you wish to save the file and where you wish to save it. Chrome and IE work the same way. I have minimal notifications and do not get a system tray notification for the above. I always just get one pop-up (where to save) for each file

Comment: This is _after_ I've told it where to save the file; I let the download run, and may switch to another window because I know how to multitask my life. When the download is complete, I get the four, not one, four, notifications in the notification area, and _that's_ what I'm questioning.

Comment: What I have seen before is that Edge will complain that a download is not complete when you move away. That may be why the extra notifications.  I do other things either in Edge in another tab or in an other application. I let the download tab stay until the download is complete.

Comment: I am _not_ closing tabs or Edge windows; I am simply going to another tab, another window, or another application. The downloads complete, and then I get _four_, not _one_, _four_ notifications that the download is complete.

Comment: I am not sure. Have you tried Resetting Edge (Start, Settings, Apps, scroll down for Edge and Repair and Reset) . I do not think this is the issue but it may be worth a try